# How to debug/print data coming in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am debugging someone else's code. It is using jqgrid to display data. This is the function where I am currently in:

```
function InitializeGrid(results)
{
    'use strict';
    $("#datagrid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: results,
        some more code here........
}
```

Problem is I want to display "results" variable on screen to see what data is coming. I have tried `alert(results)` `alert(results.length)` but it says "undefined". How do I debug/print this "results" object?